# Remainder when ${45^{17}}^{17}$ is divided by 204

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, congruences

Find the remainder when ${45^{17^{17}}}$ is divided by 204

I tried using congruence modulo. But I am not able to express it in the form of $a\equiv b\pmod{204}$.

$204=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 17$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** By the Euler-Fermat theorem we know $45^{\varphi(4)} = 45^{2} \equiv 1 \mod 4$.

By the Euler-Fermat theorem we also know $45^{\varphi(17)} = 45^{16} \equiv 1 \mod 17$

It is clear that $45 \equiv 0 \mod 3$ .

The Chinese Remainder Theorem gives us now $45^{16} \equiv 69 \mod 204$. Hence $45^{17} \equiv 69 \cdot 45 = 3105 \equiv 45 \mod 204$.

Comment: So before I can understand your answer, I have to learn Euler Fermat theorem and Chinese remainder theorem. Is this problem high school level?

Comment: @AdityaDev These are theorems that are often learned in Mathematical Olympiad training, but not in high school.

Comment: Can you recommend a book for learning number theory?

Comment: @AdityaDev For what purpose? Math olympiad, university course, or just because you are interested?

Comment: I am not preparing for any olympiads.  I am preparing for IITJEE. I am interested in learning it. I have studied vectors (and 3D geometry), calculus (single variable), geometry and pre-calculus algebra (like equations, inequalities, etc).. I lack problem solving skills. So an introductory book would suffice.

Comment: Once I comfortable with the basics, then I will go for problems like the one on my question.

Comment: @AdityaDev Fiitjee AIiTS right? You have to learn some  basic things like congruence modulo, Fermat's theorem, Euler's Phi function and related theorems, Chinese Remainder Theorem and Hensel's lemma. This should be more than enough. Don't go in for any book now, it'll be unnecessary. Use online resources.

Comment: @AritraDas Question was from Aits open test. None of them are in JEE syllabus. Fiitjee paper setters have gone mad.

Comment: @AritraDas Are we supposed to know all that for JEE?(I was sitting beside u this AITS)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$45\equiv1\pmod4\implies45^n\equiv1$

$45\equiv0\pmod3\implies45^m\equiv0$

$45\equiv11\pmod{17}$

and $17\equiv1\pmod{16}$ and $17^n\equiv1$

$\implies11^{17^{17}}\equiv11\pmod{17}$

Now apply CRT

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$45^{17}\equiv45\pmod{204}$

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: @AdityaDev: Start --> Calc --> Enter --> View --> Scientific --> $45$ --> $x^y$ --> $17$ --> Mod --> $204$ --> $=$.

Comment: Calculators are not allowed

Comment: @AdityaDev: IMO, they are not allowed when they (present time calculators) cannot be used. For $45^{17^{17}}$ they cannot be used, but for $45^{17}$ they can. So it is essentially the same as using a calculator for $45^3$, which you most likely wouldn't do by hand. You can easily do $45^{17}\bmod{204}$ by hand, if you really want to. I tried to save you some time by telling you the answer to that.

Comment: I am sorry to be asking this question, But what does 45 (mod 204) or in general a (mod b) mean?

Answer (score 1):

As $(45,204)=3$

let us start with $45^{17^{17}-1}\pmod{\dfrac{204}3}$

Using Carmichael function, $\lambda(204)=16$ and $17\equiv1\pmod{16}\implies17^{17}\equiv1$

$\implies45^{17^{17}-1}\equiv1\pmod{68}$

More generally, $a^{17^n-1}\equiv1\pmod{68}$  if $(a,68)=1$ and $n$ is a positive integer

Now, $45^{17^{17}-1}\cdot45\equiv1\cdot45\pmod{68\cdot45}$

Now using the fact: $204\mid68\cdot45,$

$$45^{17^{17}}\equiv45\pmod{204}$$