# Finding remainders with exponents on exponents

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the remained of number $25^{{6}^{2016}}$ when it is divided by 23. I´m kind of stuck, I tried to find remainders of 25 to power 3 or 2, but didn´t get anything useful from it. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644321/remainder-when-451717-is-divided-by-204/1644356#1644356

Comment: $25\equiv2$   $$6^{2015}\equiv6^5\pmod{11}$$  $$6^2\equiv3,6^3\equiv3\cdot6\equiv7\implies6^5\equiv3\cdot7\equiv10$$   $$\implies6^{2016}\equiv6\cdot10\pmod{6\cdot11}\equiv16\pmod{22}$$   So, we need $$2^{16}\pmod{23}$$  Now $2^6\equiv-5,2^{12}\equiv(-5)^2\equiv2\pmod{23}$